# Zod error handling with custom error messages on enums

Tags: typescript, enums, zod

I want to validate a gender field with Zod using `z.nativeEnum()`, But my custom error messages don't apply:

```js
gender: z.nativeEnum(Gender, {
        invalid_type_error: 'Le sexe doit être homme ou femme.',
        required_error: 'Le sexe est obligatoire',
      }),
```

but when not selecting an option the displayed error is:

[image]

What's the error here ?

Comment: This is 2023 here, somebody would crucify for making this validation lol (just kidding)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had to do it that way, by specifying `errorMap` as function returning an object holding a message field for each issue like below:

```js
  gender: z.nativeEnum(Gender, {
        errorMap: (issue, _ctx) => {
          switch (issue.code) {
            case 'invalid_type':
              return { message: 'Le sexe doit être homme ou femme.' };
            case 'invalid_enum_value':
              return { message: 'Le sexe doit être homme ou femme.' };
            default:
              return { message: 'Sexe est invalide' };
          }
        },
      }),
```

Answer (score 5):

You are missing one of the error paths `invalid_enum_value`. It's because the default option is considered a possible value: `'Sélectionnez un option'`. This option isn't one of the zod `Gender` enums

```js
gender: z.nativeEnum(Gender, {
        invalid_type_error: 'Le sexe doit être homme ou femme.',
        required_error: 'Le sexe est obligatoire',
        invalid_enum_value: 'Please select one of the options'
      }),
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped me find a solution but it doesn't solve the problem.